# Ionisation of hydrogen

Tags: atomic-physics, plasma-physics, hydrogen, electrochemistry, ionization-energy

Is ionization of hydrogen gas atoms possible? I separated hydrogen from water by electrolysis but I want to obtain H+, how do I ionize that hydrogen gas? Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Just collect that hydrogen into an container and provide the necessary ionisation energy

Comment: @RaviPrakash whatever the amount of eV it is that I need to provide but how do I provide that ionization energy to the gas collected in a container?

Comment: pointy cathode with a high enough potential should have strong enough field near the point to ionize the surrounding gas

Comment: By electric current , by using electrodes , just like electrolysis

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the hydrogen gas ($H_2$) into a gas discharge tube and apply a large enough voltage and current. Thus you can get ionized hydrogen molecules and ionized hydrogen atoms ($H^+$), i.e. protons. How a proton source works and looks like can be found [here](https://www.lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.proton_source).